# Converting from Vector3f to Matrix4f

Tags: c++, eigen

I have the following function

```
transformShape(Shape& shape, Eigen::Matrix4f transformation);
```

which obviously transforms geometrical shapes, and I have a translation in the form of a

```
Eigen::Vector3f
```

I was hoping to do something like:

```
Eigen::Vector3f myVector = //calculate 
Eigen::Matrix4f mat = Eigen::Matrix4f::Identity();
mat = myVector * mat;
transformShape(shape, mat);
```

But this is not possible since I'm multiplying structures with different dimensions, so my question is how to convert a Vector3f into a Translation or Vector with 4 dimensions

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Translation matrix of vector (x,y,z) is of form

```
1 0 0 x
0 1 0 y
0 0 1 z
0 0 0 1
```

Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_matrix

There is also Eigen::Translation which you can use:

```
Vector3f v(1,2,3);
Matrix4f m = Affine3f(Translation3f(v)).matrix();
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a raw Matrix4f you can use an Eigen::Transform<> object that encapsulate a Matrix4f with convenient functions. For instance, if your transformation is affine, use an [Affine3f](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TutorialGeometry.html).

```
Affine3f T;
T.matrix() = mat; // T.matrix() gives you full access to the underlying Matrix4f
Vector3f a, b;
a = mat * b;
```

See the previous link for more details on space transformations with Eigen.

Answer (score 0):

A Vector4 should have a value of 0.0 in the 4th element.

If it was a Point3 it would be extended to a Point4 by using a value of 1.0.

This component is known as "w" and a search for "Vector4 w" will give some results such as:
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/14115/do-i-need-the-w-component-in-my-vector-class

Comment: yes, but it is not possible in eigen to multiply a Matrix4f with Vector4, I get the error  error: ‘INVALID_MATRIX_PRODUCT’ is not a member of ‘Eigen::internal::static_assertion<false>’. also it is possible to multiply mat * vecvtor.matrix() but I get the same error

Comment: The line mat = myVector * mat; is invalid. mat * myVector is ok but it returns a Vector4f, not a 4x4 matrix!